# Creating Postgres in Kubernetes with Crunchy Data

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I am trying to create a postgres cluster in kubernetes using Crunchy Data.  I am new to Crunchy Data and trying to get my head around the documentation and need some help.

I am using NFS storage and have created the persistent volumes using this example specified in https://github.com/CrunchyData/crunchy-containers/blob/master/examples/kube/custom-config-ssl/custom-config-ssl-pv-nfs.json.  I am not sure if this is the right way of doing it.

I am now trying to create the cluster using pgo and not sure what the arguments are supposed to be on pgo create cluster to make sure it is HA and leverages the PVCs.

I have read a lot of documentation, but it is just not clear to me, can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

you can create crunchydata clusters using pgo client.

https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/postgres-operator/4.7.5/quickstart/

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) are considered very low quality and [can get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), please put the important parts from the linked resource into the answer body.